# Evaluating a limit containing an integral.

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

A little bit of background first.

A while ago I was trying to evaluate $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan^2\left(x\right)}{\sqrt{x}\left(a^2+x^2\right)}\ dx$$ with $a>1$ and approaching $1$ from above, using techniques of contour integration. I've recently come back to this problem. It turns out that after shuffling stuff around, we are left with: $$2\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan^2\left(x\right)}{\sqrt{x}\left(1+x^2\right)}\ dx\ =-\pi\sqrt{2}\lim\limits_{a \to 1^{+}}\left[\frac{1}{4}\ln^2{\left(\frac{a-1}{a+1}\right)}-\int_0^1 {2\operatorname{artanh}\left(x\right)\over \sqrt{x}\left(a^2-x^2\right)} \ dx\right]-\frac{\pi^2\sqrt{2}}{2}\ln{2}$$

I'm really interested in finding a way to evaluate the limit above. I'm not entirely sure if it helps that much, but it can be rewritten as:
$$-\pi\sqrt{2}\lim\limits_{a \to 1^{+}}\left[\operatorname{arcoth^2}\left(a\right)-\int_a^\infty {2\operatorname{arcoth}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\sqrt{x}\over x^2-1} \ dx\right]$$

Since the value of $\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan^2\left(x\right)}{\sqrt{x}\left(1+x^2\right)}\ dx$ is known, we can see that the limit is actually equal to: $$\frac{1}{48}\pi\sqrt{2}\left(5\pi^2+12\pi\ln{\left( 2\right)}-12\ln^2{\left( 2\right)}\right)$$

My guess is that the integral inside of the limit should somehow be "persuaded" to spit out an $\operatorname{arcoth^2}{\left(a\right)}$ term, but I'm still looking for a way to achieve it.

I would be most grateful for some tips on how to attack this problem. Thank you in advance!